# What are DRVs and RDIs in "daily values" (DVs) for nutrition labeling?

Tags: nutrition, regulatory-agencies

The U.S. Food and Drug Administration (FDA) set ["Daily Values" (DVs) for labeling foods](https://ods.od.nih.gov/HealthInformation/dailyvalues.aspx/) that are comprised of Daily Reference Values (DRVs) and the Reference Daily Intakes
(RDIs).  From [here](https://www.fda.gov/media/99069/download):

> Daily Values are comprised of two sets of reference values for reporting nutrients in
> nutrition labels—the Daily Reference Values (DRVs) and the Reference Daily Intakes
> (RDIs). To limit consumer confusion, the single term “Daily Value” is used to designate
> both the DRVs and RDIs.

**What are the official definitions of DRVs and RDIs, and what is the exact difference?**

Perhaps one is maximum (don't eat more than this much fat), and one is minimum suggested (have at least this much vitamin C)?

I see that perhaps:

- [DRVs](https://www.fda.gov/media/99059/download) are for food components (the same as macro-nutrients?)
- [RDIs](https://www.fda.gov/media/99069/download) are for nutrients

**Are all DRVs recommended maximums, and all RDIs recommended minimums?**

(I understand that they are for a hypothetical reference diet of 2,000 calories for adults and children 4 years and older, and 1,000 calories for children 1 to 3 years of age.)